# Complex iteration over PyTables

Tags: python, pytables

If anyone is into handling Pytables maybe could give me a clue about this complex expression which is not working:

```
hdf5file = openFile("savedTable.h5", mode = 'r')
tab = hdf5file.getNode("/Data")

for i in xrange(1,10):
            result = [result + 1 for x in tab.where("""(col1== 1) & (col2 == 1) & (col3== i) & ((col4 == 1) | (col5 == 1) | (col6 == 1) | (col7== 1))""")]
```

What Spyder is giving me is just this typical message **"Invalid Syntax"**

Special atention to the loop **"for i in ...."** and in the query **"... & (col3==i)"** I do not know if this part can be done like that.

Comment: Instead of `result = [result + 1 for x ...` do you mean `result = [x + 1 for x ...`?

Comment: I don't know, probably yes, what I want is to increment "result" by 1, if the condition in the query is found. Since I am not giving x any value, I was thinking that is not possible to do something like x + 1, but I will try. Thanks

Comment: In that case, try `result += sum(1 for _ in ...)` or `result += len(tab.where(...))`

Comment: Are you sure about it? I don't think this kind of table iterator tab.where can be used with len() method.....but I can try anyway

Comment: Can you post the full traceback please?

Comment: no Joel, I finally went around it, but it was long time ago so I do not even know where I have that script. Anyway thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You're right, you can't do this:

```
for i in xrange(1,10):
    tab.where('col3 == i')
```

Instead, try:

```
for i in xrange(1,10):
    cond = 'col3 == %d' % i
    tab.where(cond)
```